# how can I change the Spring MVC commandName name?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I writting a web application in Spring MVC as following

```
@Controller
public class LoginFormController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Login handler(){ 

        Login login = new Login();

        return login;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView onSubmit(Login login){ 

        String name = login.getUsername();

        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        model.put("name", name);

        return new ModelAndView("success", "model", model);
    }
}
```

Here is the jsp:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/include.jsp" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html>
<head>
<title>Spring Sample - Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Login Page</h3><br/>
    <form:form commandName="login" method="POST"> 
        Username:<form:input path="username"/> 
        <font color="red"><form:errors path="username"/></font><br/><br/> 
        Password:<form:password path="password"/> 
        <font color="red"><form:errors path="password"/></font><br/><br/> 
        <input type="submit" value="Login"/> 
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works fine, but if I want to change the commandName="login" to login2, just as follows:

@Controller
public class LoginFormController {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Login handler(){ 

    Login login2 = new Login();

    return login2;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView onSubmit(Login login2){ 

    String name = login2.getUsername();

    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    model.put("name", name);

    return new ModelAndView("success", "model", model);
}
```

}

I get this error:

Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'login2' available as request attribute.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following :

```
@ModelAttribbute("login") Login login2
```

to your handler method , like the following :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView onSubmit(@ModelAttribbute("login") Login login2){ 

    String name = login2.getUsername();

    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    model.put("name", name);

    return new ModelAndView("success", "model", model);
}
```

the reason of the error , is that you are saying you are submiting an object called "login" from your form , but in the handler method , your object name is "login2" , so if you add @ModelAttribute annotaion in the handler method , you can specify the name of the commandName.

Hope that Helps .

Comment: As far as i discovered, some how spring uses class name of the object i'm returning as the commandName. This allows me to use any variable name i want in the get/post handlers.

Comment: but if you want to name your object with something different than the commandName , use the @ModelAttribute